# HTTP Post on F5

Tags: http, browser, post, get

Why is the default behavior of all the browsers to do HTTP POST when refreshing a page? And to submit the forms.

This often leads to the well-known 'you're going to submit this page twice' sort of message.
Which can easily(if not taken care of) execute a transcation twice (say if you're buying something).

Isn't this weird?

Answer (score 3):

It's a quite standard behaviour because the state of the resource you're visiting was created by being Posted to.

Refreshing the page should re-initiate the page's state and thus a post is required.

Most of the time it's more ideal to use the [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern so that users are presented with a resource who's state is not dependent on a server Post.